# Liquibase cascade DELETE many to many based on WHERE clause

Tags: sql, liquibase

Is it possible to cascade delete with Liquibase xml?

For example, let's say I have the following tables and I want to delete a row from Drivers. I would also want to delete any related rows from CarDrivers.

```
Table Cars:
CarID      int
CarName    nvarchar(100)

Table Drivers:
DriverID   int
DriverName nvarchar(100)

Table CarDrivers:
CarID      int
DriverID   int
```

An SQL that would do the trick would look something like:

```
DELETE
FROM CarDrivers cd
WHERE cd.DriverID IN (
    SELECT ID 
    FROM Drivers d 
    WHERE d.DriverName IN ("John", "Smith")
);

DELETE
FROM Drivers
WHERE DriverName IN ("John", "Smith");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put the sql inside a xml changelog file using **< sql >** change type. You can find more details on this page: https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/sql.html